# Command to check in c >= or <= for mips

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I am solving a college activity, I would like to know which command to check if one value is less than or equal to another.

I need to pass the code below c to mips

Assume that vector V is associated with the base register $ s6, and the variables a, b, c, d are associated with
registers $ s0, $ s1, $ s2, $ s3. Convert the C language statement to MIPS.

```
f)
if( V[8] >= 12) {
 a = a + b + c;
 V[8] = V[8] + a;
} else {
 a = a – b – c;
 V[8] = V[8] + a;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a dedicated program to do this? I believe they're called [compilers...](https://godbolt.org/z/5t4g1s)

Answer (score 0):

to check for >= and <=, you can perform a subtraction between your two values and use a BGEZ (branch on greater than or equal to zero) or BLEZ (branch on less than or equal to zero) depending on which result you want.

Example: r0 <= r1

SUB r2 r0 r1;
BLEZ r2;

Comment: Note that this will fail if the subtract overflows.  For a single comparison (as is needed in the OPs posted C code), a BGE or BLE is better (doesn't have overflow issues).